# Convergence of the series with probability 1...

Tags: probability

There are given random variables: $X_1, X_2,...$ which are independent. Moreover: $P(X_n = -n) = P(X_n = n) = \frac{1}{n^3}, P(X_n = 0) = 1 - \frac{2}{n^3}$, $n = 1,2,...$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ is convergent with probability $=1$. May anyone help?

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem

Answer (score 2):

The series $\sum\limits_nP[X_n\ne0]$ converges hence Borel-Cantelli lemma guarantees the existence of a (random) integer $N$, almost surely finite, such that $X_n=0$ for every $n\geqslant N$. Thus, $X_n\ne0$ for at most a finite number of indices $n$, in particular $\sum\limits_nX_n$ converges almost surely.

The independence property is not needed. The values that $X_n$ takes when $X_n\ne0$ are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As we deal with a series of *independent* random variables, it's enough to show that the sequence $(S_n=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j,n\geqslant 1)$ is convergent in distribution. The characteristic function of $S_n$ is 
$$\varphi_n(t)=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+2\frac{\cos(jt)-1}{j^3}\right).$$
The remaining task is to show pointwise convergence of this product to a function which is continuous at $0$. Then we will be able to conclude by a theorem of Lévy.